# using for Loop to build a file name and save it

Tags: python, for-loop

```
for i in range(1,151):
 Path = './Result/Normal_%d'%i
 Normal_i.to_csv(Path, sep=',' , header=None , index=None)
```

I would like to use for loop to save a file
that is name Normal_1, Normal_2 ...Normal_150
and I found out that using "Normal_i" in for loop makes an error.
What Can I do to save a file that is named Normal_1, Normal_2 in for loop?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
Path = './Result/Normal'
for i in range(1,151):
 Normal_i.to_csv(Path+str(i), sep=',' , header=None , index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good answer has already been given, but here is a fun python thing you could try:

```py
eval(f"Normal_i.to_csv({Path}File{i}, sep=',' , header=None , index=None)")
```

About [eval()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval).

PS: I do not endorse doing this.

Comment: Why to use ```eval``` unnecessarily?

Comment: `eval` is the opposite of pythonic. It's like using an excavator to hammer down a nail.

Comment: You should read this: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)